# How to run the maximum number of threads possible on your computer

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

How to run the maximum number of threads possible on your computer ?
I want to run the maximum number of threads in my python code.
I run the code on a Windows computer.

I thought about the following solution:

```
x = 0
while 1:
    try:
        t = Thread(target=learn, args=(line,)) #writer,))
        thread_list.append(t)
        t.start()
        break
    except Exception as exp:
        time.sleep(1)
        if x == 0:
            print "Waiting for free thread",
            x = 1
        else:
            print ".",
```

The code worked fine but after a few minutes I got the following error:

```
mutex.acquire() #error
with open("output.csv", "ab") as dataset_file:
    writer = csv.writer(dataset_file)
    writer.writerow(dataset)
mutex.release()

mutex.acquire()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'acquire'
```

Does anyone have a way to fix my error or another method to open the maximum amount of threads?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum number of threads you can run on Windows depend on how much memory you have.  Each thread in Windows consumes by default 1MB of RAM for stack (plus some more for its context and a tiny kernel-mode stack).  For a 32-bit app, the maximum number of threads you can create is about ~1800, provided you don't allocate any other memory.  In other words, how many threads you can create boils down to how much free memory you application has.

But, you should not create too many threads.  Normally, you should aim to have as many threads as cores available.  Creating threads is expensive, switching between threads - too.

Comment: Matching the number of threads to the number of cores is good advice for other languages, as it allows a cpu-bound program to use all cores at once and maybe thereby obtain a speedup proportional to the number of cores — but note that due to cpython’s Global Interpreter Lock, a multithreaded python program is unlikely to obtain any additional speed from multi threading, regardless of how many threads it uses.